# SwiftUI View does not updated when ObservedObject changed

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, observable, swiftui

I have a content view where i'm showing a list of items using ForEach

```
@ObservedObject var homeVM : HomeViewModel

var body: some View {
    ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Spacer().frame(width:8)
            ForEach(homeVM.favoriteStores , id: \._id){ item in
                StoreRowOneView(storeVM: item)
            }
            Spacer().frame(width:8)
        }
    }.frame(height: 100)
}
```

And my `ObservableObject` contains

`@Published var favoriteStores = [StoreViewModel]()`

And `StoreViewModel` is defined as below

```
class StoreViewModel  : ObservableObject {
    @Published var store:ItemStore

    init(store:ItemStore) {
        self.store = store
    }

    var _id:String {
        return store._id!
    }
}
```

If i fill the array directly it work fine , and i can see the  list of stores 
but if i filled the array after a network call (background job) , the view did not get notified that there is a change

```
 StoreApi().getFavedStores(userId: userId) { (response) in
            guard response != nil else {
                self.errorMsg = "Something wrong"
                self.error = true
                return
            }
            self.favoriteStores = (response)!.map(StoreViewModel.init)
            print("counnt favorite \(self.favoriteStores.count)")
        }
```

But the weird thing is : 
 - if i add a text which show the count of the array items , the view will get notified and everything work fine

That's what i mean :

```
    @ObservedObject var homeVM : HomeViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Spacer().frame(width:8)
                ForEach(homeVM.favoriteStores , id: \._id){ item in
                    StoreRowOneView(storeVM: item)
                }
                Text("\(self.homeVM.favoriteStores.count)").frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Spacer().frame(width:8)
            }
        }.frame(height: 100)
    }
```

Any explaining for that ?

Comment: I am facing exact same problem. No luck though. I am stuck on it for days now. The ViewModel updates after network call but list stops updating after that. When I print the object after network calls, it gives me expected values but view does not updates.

Comment: @Ishmeet update me if you found a solution for this problem please

Comment: I did not find a solution yet. I think this is a SwiftUI Bug.

Comment: @Ishmeet - Did you guys find a solution by now? I have the same problem but I am using List View. My List has always 2 cells & the cells are loaded correct with static info, when I hit a webservice & updated the model, the view no longer readjusts. When I print the model objects they are updated with latest data..  Plz let update the post if you guys found any solution

Comment: @Dinakar we did find a solution by refactoring to use the right combination of State/ObservableObject/Binding. We made sure that our object is owned by the parent as State. However, while passing the object downstream we used Binding and ObservedObject Property Wrapper. This video from WWDC helped us achieve the result: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/ . If you can share your code, I might be able to help better.

Comment: @OuailBellal were you able to fix your problem?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the input.

Comment: In my case the souce of truth is maintained as expected. I used VIP in my app and the View is binded to ViewModel, which is Observable object. The actual problem in my case was the view is missing a ViewModel.

Comment: The body of my listview is called multiple times & each time the constructor creates a new view object. In this coarse the latest view that is loaded on window is not observing the changes but someone (may be deinitialized by now). I fixed by making the View singleton & reuse the view for all the objects in the list. When a cell is selected, I store the object on my Appcontroller (an object that holds app specific data used at multiple places) & on appear of the view assign the model to the ViewModel..   I am not sure if this is the solution though :(

Comment: I have a List view(1) under a Navigation View. On Selecting one of the cell, I show the details(2) (Which is again a List View). On selecting one of the row on (2), I load a view with 2 rows.   The navigations from (1) to (2) & from (2) to (3) is done via Navigation Link.  If I debug the body is called for the first time to load the list. When a row is selected the body is again called.. infact each interaction calls the body of 2 & 3 too.. I just didn't follow the OS execution of Navigation Bar & Navigation link objects. Does this happen to you too?

Answer (score 3):

For horizontal ScrollView you need to have your height fixed or just use  conditional ScrollView which will show when `someModels.count > 0`

```swift
var body: some View {
   ScrollView(.horizontal) {
      HStack() {
         ForEach(someModels, id: \.someParameter1) { someModel in
            someView(someModel)
         }
      }.frame(height: someFixedHeight)
   }
}
// or
var body: some View {
   VStack {
      if someModels.count > 0 {
         ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack() {
               ForEach(someModels, id: \.someParameter1) { someModel in
                  someView(someModel)
               }
            }
         }
      } else {
        EmptyView()
        // or other view
      }
   }
}
```

Properly conforming to Hashable protocol by implementing

```swift
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { 
   hasher.combine(someParameter1)
   hasher.combine(someParameter2)
}
```

and

```swift
static func == (lhs: SomeModel, rhs: SomeModel) -> Bool {
   lhs.someParameter1 == rls.someParameter1 && lhs.someParameter2 == rls.someParameter2

}
```

And also following @Asperi suggestion of using proper id from model, which must be unique to every element.

```swift
ForEach(someModels, id: \.someParameter1) { someModel in
    someView(someModel)
}
```

There is no other way for `ForEach` to notify updates other than unique ids.

`Text(someModels.count)` was working because it is notifying the changes as count is being changed.

Answer (score 2):

Share some experiences that might help.

When I used ScrollView + ForEach + fetch, nothing shows until I trigger view refresh via other means. It shows normally when I supply fixed data without fetching. I solved it by specifying .infinity width for ScrollView.

My theory is that ForEach re-renders when fetch completes, but ScrollView somehow does not adjust its width to fit the content.

It is similar in your case. By supplying fixed width Text, ForEach can calculate its width during init, and ScrollView can use that to adjust its width. But in case of fetch, ForEach has initial 0 content width, and so is ScrollView. When fetch completes ScrollView does not update its width accordingly.

Giving ScrollView some initial width should solve your problem.

Comment: You just saved me a tonne of time. I'm working on a firebase project and I had this EXACT thing happen to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would start from forwarding results to the main queue, as below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.favoriteStores = (response)!.map(StoreViewModel.init)
}
```

Next... `ForEach` tracks `id` parameters, so you should be sure that results have different `_id` s in the following, otherwise ForEach is not marked as needed to update

```
ForEach(homeVM.favoriteStores , id: \._id){ item in
    StoreRowOneView(storeVM: item)
}
```

Comment: ForEach is worked fine when i add another Text outside it , which sho the count of stores , so the id was not the problem , and for `DispatchQueue` , i think that i'm on the main thread , i don't need it , and also it work fine after adding a Text , which is really weird

Answer (score 0):

What is ItemStore? more importantly

```
ForEach(homeVM.favoriteStores , id: \._id){ item in
    StoreRowOneView(storeVM: item)
}
```

what is `_id` i believe your `_id` is same each time so it will not update the list. You have to put `id:` some variable that you want to re-render the list when it changed.

Update: If you do not have any other variable to take its value as reference than you can use

```
ForEach((0..<homeVM.favoriteStores.count)) { index in
    StoreRowOneView(storeVM:: homeVM.favoriteStores[index])
}
```